# I need to run a terminal command on startup of a raspberry pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi3, samba

I am building my own little server out of a raspberry pi using samba and I need to run

```
sudo service smbd start
```

on start-up so that in the case of a power down it will automatically restart samba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable a service to make it start at boot

```
sudo service smbd enable
```

Comment: If you run this as `root` you will obviously not need the `sudo`.